# java file picker with inline thumbnails

Tags: java, swing, filechooser

I need a nautilus-style file picker in java, where the files are shown "gallery-style" with a customisable thumbnail for each file. Is it possible to make the standard open file dialog do this? If not, does anyone know of an open-sourced widget that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want one callback per file to display its thumbnail preview as its icon.

I think @davetron5000 suggestion may still be useful: As shown in [*How to Use File Choosers*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html), the [FileChooserDemo2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#FileChooserDemo2) example demonstrates an approach to constructing thumnails. It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it may be a good starting point. You'd update your preview pane in response to `DIRECTORY_CHANGED_PROPERTY`, rather than  `SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY`.

Addendum: [`org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html) with a custom [`TableCellRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) might be an interesting alternative.

Comment: my problem with a preview pane is you need to click on each file before you can see its preview. that really doesn't scale if the user needs to pick from a list of images whose filenames are meaningless.

Comment: Link updated. `DIRECTORY_CHANGED_PROPERTY` provides access to the whole directory; you'd have to fire the event manually for the initial level and synchronize selections. The example depends on a file's extension, but sniffing might be possible.

Comment: thanks,missed the DIRECTORY_CHANGED_PROPERTY. still feels a bit like i'm fighting with the jfilechooser, but i'll mark this as accepted

Comment: I empathize with the "fighting" aspect of this approach. Rather than adding a new answer, I've suggested an alternative above.

Answer (score 2):

The `JFileChooser` allows you access to a custom area where you can add whatever UI elements you'd like.  It's available via [`setAccessory(JComponent)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setAccessory%28javax.swing.JComponent%29) as documented in the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setAccessory%28javax.swing.JComponent%29).

Comment: no, i don't want an accessory for the whole filechooser, i want one callback per file to display its thumbnail preview as its icon

Answer (score 0):

I suppose *nautilus* is the KDE file manager.

I don't no if that is available for KDE, but for Windows i usally use the (Eclipse) [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) file chooser, because it is more native than the pure Swing implementation.

[Example here](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet72.java?view=co)

Comment: nautilus is the gnome file manager. but i just presented it as an example of the ui i want. i don't want a native file manager, i want a gallery widget where the user can select a file by thumbnail rather than filename.